# Constructing message packet for serial port on Arduino

Tags: serial-port, signal-processing, arduino-uno, serial-communication, arduino-c++

I'm working with a device that receive data if only if you send it in the correct way, following a packet structure. The device has its manual and say this:
[Image extracted from the B-Alert User Manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JarH8.png)
[According to the Baud Rate, you select the packet type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32gzQ.png)

But the device does not recognize the data I'm sending and I supposed that is because I'm not sending in the correct way the packet structure (because I've already check the cables, the ports, the device) and they work well, so , that's why I think the problem is in the code.

BTW, I'm using the MAX232 from arduino (because the device has an RS232 entry)

```
byte Flg1 = 0x56;
byte Flg2 = 0x5A;

byte pLength1 = 0x00; // pLength1 = 0x00
byte pLength2 = 0x02; //0x0A; // pLength2 = #data

byte pType=0x3;//01; //0XB; According to the data // (pType=#data+1) v (pLength1:pLength2)

byte data1=0; //For the MSB
byte data2=0; // For the LSB

double d1=0.01;
int var;

byte checksum=0;
byte sum=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  delay(200);
}

void loop() {
  var=d1*100.0;
  data2 = var&0x00FF; //bitwise AND LSB 
  // -> Right side -> These values stay in the same position
  data1 = (var&0xFF00)>>8; // bitwise AND MSB 
  // -> from left side to right side -> the MSB stay in then they move to the right side

  sum = pLength1+pLength2+pType+data1+data2;
  checksum = 255-(sum%256);

  //Sending the bytes                             BIG ENDIAN
  //                                              High priority first
  int pABM[] = {Flg1,Flg2,pLength1,pLength2,pType,data1,data2,checksum};

  char char_pABM[9] = {pABM[0],pABM[1],pABM[2],pABM[3],pABM[4],pABM[5],
                       pABM[6],pABM[7]};

  Serial.write(char_pABM[0]);
  Serial.write(char_pABM[1]);
  Serial.write(char_pABM[2]);
  Serial.write(char_pABM[3]);
  Serial.write(char_pABM[4]);
  Serial.write(char_pABM[5]);
  Serial.write(char_pABM[6]);
  Serial.write(char_pABM[7]); 

  delay(500);
}
```

That is the code that I tried, and I'm expecting to send just "1" in the data, because it is supposed to show in a software just a signal (like a change from 0 to 1). But it shows nothing.

Comment: "*But it shows nothing.*" --  That is just a summation that tells us nothing. You need to learn how to report a problem with details, and/or debug your program. What is the output of your program? What does the packet that is sent look like, i.e what are the byte values? Why is there both an integer array and a byte array of the packet?